# export 'credit_card' was not found in 'vee-validate/dist/rules

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I'm using veevalidade 3, with vue 2 and nuxt 2.

While using rules such as email, required, min and max works fine, when i try to use credit_card i get the following error:

```
"export 'credit_card' was not found in 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
```

The documentation says that this rule comes included, but i searched in the **/node_modules/vee-validate/dist/rules.js** file i didn't find any mention about it.

How can i get this rule to work ?

plugin file **vee-validate.js**:

```js
import { extend } from "vee-validate";
import { required, email, min, credit_card } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
extend("required", {
  ...required,
  message: "Este campo é obrigatório.",
});

extend("credit_card", credit_card)

extend("email", {
  ...email,
  message: "Informe um e-mail válido.",
});
```

Comment: The credit card rule looks to have been removed in V3 of vee validate.  There are articles online that suggest various regex patterns to at least check that a card is syntactically valid